# ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter as a fragment itself?

Tags: android, android-fragments

is it possible for a View Pager with FragmentPagerAdapter to be its own fragment and not a fragment activity?

Here is a picture of what I mean.

http://d3a0c3fa3t59bz.cloudfront.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/timetable1.png

Notice on the left most side its a view pager with Thursday and Friday. This is the kind of arrangement I am looking for a fragment view pager as a fragment itself.

If someone could post an example, advice or provide a link to carry this out, I would be most grateful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though you have to use nested fragments, which have given many developers headaches.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested) demonstrates how it works. Here is the `PagerFragment` from that sample that hosts the `ViewPager`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.pagernested;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PagerFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager, container, false);
    ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)result.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    pager.setAdapter(buildAdapter());

    return(result);
  }

  private PagerAdapter buildAdapter() {
    return(new SampleAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager()));
  }
}
```

Note how the `SampleAdapter` is passed `getChildFragmentManager()` from the `Fragment`, not `getFragmentManager()`. This allows the `SampleAdapter` to use fragments, which will be nested inside the outer fragment (`PagerFragment`). Beyond that, the rest of the `ViewPager` implementation should be the same as if the `ViewPager` were hosted by an activity directly.

Comment: Thank you. I am going through the sample project now